# Why is the loading backdrop not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In my app I load data from an api, sometimes there is more than one request necessary (i.e. loading the main data and loading the options of a select field).

My idea is to have a global state in a context (an array in this case), where I add an unique string before the api request and when the request has finished and has returned its data, this unique string is removed from the array. As long as the array length is greater than zero, the loading component is shown and if there are two different api requests that take different times, the loading component isn't removed until the last request has ended.

My problem is, that the loading component mostly is still shown, even if the "stop function" has removed the unique string and the array is empty.

This is my code so far:

**ContextProvider** (./contexts/LoadingContext.jsx):

```
'use strict';

import React, {
    createContext,
    useContext,
    useState,
} from 'react';

const LoadingContext = createContext({
    startLoading: (id) => {},
    stopLoading: (id) => {},
    isLoading: false,
});


export const useLoading = () => useContext(LoadingContext);

export const LoadingProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState([]);

    const startLoading = (id) => {
        setLoading([...loading, id]);
    };

    const stopLoading = (id) => {
        const _loading = [...loading];
        const index = _loading.indexOf(id);
        if(index !== -1) {
            _loading.splice(index, 1);
            setLoading(_loading);
        }
    };

    return (
        <LoadingContext.Provider value={{
            startLoading: startLoading,
            stopLoading: stopLoading,
            isLoading: loading.length > 0,
        }}>
            {children}
        </LoadingContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

**GlobalLoadingBackdrop** (./GlobalLoadingBackdrop.jsx):

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import Backdrop from '@mui/material/Backdrop';
import CircularProgress from '@mui/material/CircularProgress';
import { useLoading } from './contexts/LoadingContext';

export const GlobalLoadingBackdrop = () => {

    const { isLoading} = useLoading();

    return (
        <Backdrop
            sx={{
                color: '#fff',
                zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.modal + 1,
            }}
            open={isLoading}
        >
            <CircularProgress color={'inherit'} />
        </Backdrop>
    );
}
```

**Usage somewhere in a functional component**:

```
const { startLoading, stopLoading } = useLoading();

try {
    // start loading
    startLoading('GET/some/api/request');
    // call api
    const response = await axios.get('/some/api/request');
    // check response
    if(response.hasOwnProperty('error') && response.error !== null) {
        throw new Error(response.errorMessage);
    }
    // do somthing with the data
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
} finally {
    // stop loading
    stopLoading('GET/some/api/request');
}
```

Any help or idea how to solve the problem will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error might be caused by the way you are setting and removing the `ids` from the `loading` array. You are using the spread operator to create a new array, but you are also mutating the original array with `splice`. This might cause some inconsistency and confusion for React.

A better way to update the loading array is to use a functional update, which means passing a function to setLoading that receives the previous array as an argument, and returns a new array based on it. This way, you always use the latest array value. For example:

```
const startLoading = (id) => {
  setLoading((prevLoading) => [...prevLoading, id]);
};

const stopLoading = (id) => {
  setLoading((prevLoading) => prevLoading.filter((item) => item !== id));
};
```

And I think you can use `useTransition` hook which is newly introduced in React 18 for loading.

To learn more, please see [documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useTransition).

Comment: Your solution does the trick, I used the functional update before, but haven't thought it might help here... thanks...

Comment: @bohrsty, You're welcome, I'm glad my solution helped you. A functional update is useful when you want to update some state multiple times in one event, or when you want to use the latest state value, regardless of batching or not. I hope this helps you understand what functional updates are and how to use them.